# Profiling an azure webrole with vs profiler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, profiling

I've found tons of blogs/info on running the builtin VS profiler on an Azure solution and it does in fact work as expected on the worker role projects.  However, When I profile an ASP.NET web role, all of the data for the w3wp.exe refuses to load symbols so I am left with a long list of hex addresses and timing information I can't relate back to code.  When I open the vsp file I get a lot of symbol resolution failures, as well as this:

> VSP2340: Environment variables were not properly set during profiling run and managed >symbols may not resolve.  Please use vsperfclrenv before profiling

Except I didnt run vsperf or anything else, the only way to enable profiling is via the "Publish" action on an Azure project, which does whatever magic necessary behind the scenes.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get these symbols to resolve, or even a way to get these symbols to match up to functions (I have the relevant pdbs)

Screenshot of my results:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963604/deploy-pdbs-on-an-azure-web-role/13106553#13106553