# Building and package ccproj with TFS 2013 release

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to build a Cloud Service Package with TFS 2013.

Its a ccproj file and this is the MSBuild Arguments

```
/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Composite.WindowsAzure.Package.XS /p:PublishDir=\\core03\AzureBuild\AzureBuild /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0 /p:EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
```

It builds fine, but the package is 15mb instead of 8mb that my own local machine produces. When looknig inside the package, it have put the webrole.pdb file for the website also, so it looks like it didnt build in release mode.

Not sure where to configure this.

The build log can be found at: http://pastebin.com/ad1CCGrC if its any help for helping me.

This implies that it is in release mode:

```
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
         Copying file from "obj\Release\WebRoleBoot.dll" to "C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.dll".
         Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot -> C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.dll
         Copying file from "obj\Release\WebRoleBoot.pdb" to "C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.pdb".
```

This indicate that something might be wrong: (we have verified that 4.5 is installed though)

```
 3>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot.csproj]
     3>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot.csproj]
     3>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot.csproj]
     3>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Web", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot.csproj]
       GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
       Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       CoreCompile:
       Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
         Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot -> C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.dll
       _CopyWebApplicationLegacy:
         Copying Web Application Project Files for Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.SimpleBoot
       CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly:
         Gather all files from Project items @(IntermediateAssembly). Adding:
         C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.dll to bin\WebRoleBoot.dll
         C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\bin\WebRoleBoot.pdb to bin\WebRoleBoot.pdb
       CollectFilesFromContent:
```

We just found out that, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\4.5 was missing on the build server.

So the package is now down from 15mb to 10mb. So alsmost identical to the 8mb package my local machine produces. The build server still has a pbd file for webrole.dll and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll that my local do not.

Also, in the log I found /debug:pdbonly in the csc compile command:

```
CoreCompile:
         C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Composite.WindowsAzure.1.0.0.4\lib\net45\Composite.WindowsAzure.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Composite.WindowsAzure.Webrole.1.0.0.4\lib\net45\Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Unity.3.0.1304.1\lib\Net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Unity.3.0.1304.1\lib\Net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Microsoft.Web.Administration.7.0.0.0\lib\net20\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.2.1.0.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Client.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\System.Spatial.5.2.0\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll" /reference:"C:\Builds\1\Freja\Azure Packages 1\src\WindowsAzure\Public\packages\Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow.4.5.11\lib\portable-net45+win8\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\WebRoleBoot.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs WebRole.cs "C:\Users\Core03TfsService\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

Comment: Did you tried this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963604/deploy-pdbs-on-an-azure-web-role

Comment: Thats about adding the debug things. I need to compile the release build but TFS dont, it just give me a debug build and I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

If the pdbs are included then its the chk/debug build. Change the build from debug to release in your build process template. See how @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd647547.aspx#configs

Comment: I have changed it to Release with the exact same behavior. If i run the msbuild manually on my own machine it do it right, and if i run it manually on the build server with exactly the same properties it do it wrong. Further more on build server it seems to put alot more warnings out, its also like it uses the /Frameworks/v4.0xxx instead of /Frameworks/x64/. The build server have only vs2010 isntalled, is this important?

Comment: the tfs build package also contains dll mscorlib ect, where my local build do not.

Comment: I will add the build log.