# Azure WebJobs Include PDB

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to find out how to include the PDB files when I upload a Publish an Azure WebJob

This article explains how to do this for a normal website [Deploy PDBs on an Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963604/deploy-pdbs-on-an-azure-web-role) but I've been unable to find anything for WebJobs

Do I just need to manually copy them up to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually include the files in the Publish section of the project properties. See attached screen shot. Under Publish, select "Application Files" and then click the "Show all files" box. You should then see the PDB files and be able to include them. I didn't see a simple check box, as you would see for a Web Deploy.

[image: Publish Screen Shot]